# How to extract Thumbnail of MP4 Video located in azure storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to extract a thumbnail from an mp4 video hosted in azure storage.  My current method in C# uses a NReco NuGet package:

But that is a local file.  How do i extract the thumb from an azure storage file.

```
string mp4inputpath = server.mappath("~/testfolder/myvideo.mp4");
string thumbOutputPath = server.mappath("~/testfolder/mythumb.jpg");
var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
// Get the thumb at the frame 1 second into the video
ffMpeg.GetVideoThumbnail(mp4inputpath, thumbOutputPath, 1);
```

That works! But i need to use an azure storage file url for mp4inputpath.

I can download the mp4 file from azure storage and save it temporarily into my azure web app.  I can do that programatically.

Then extract the thumb, ie,
ffMpeg.GetVideoThumbnail(mp4inputpath, thumbOutputPath, 1);

Then delete the temporary mp4 within my app.

this works but i don't know it is advisable to download mp4 files into my azure web app.  I don't know if it will scale.  This is the only solution i have,  so far.

```
string mp4Url = @"https://mysorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mp4/vacation/summer/dogbarking.mp4";
string thumbOutputPath = server.mappath("~/testfolder/mythumb.jpg");
var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
// Get the thumb at the frame 1 second into the video
ffMpeg.GetVideoThumbnail(mp4Url, thumbOutputPath, 1);
```

This does not seem to work.  No Error, but the thumbOutputPath file is empty.

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is pretty much what you have to do, since you cannot open an object in Azure Storage as you would a local file. So, grabbing the file into a local file or a stream is what you'd need to do.

As far as scaling: that will depend on the size (and number of instances) you're running in your Web App. Just be aware that you should have both your storage account and your Web App in the same region, to reduce latency and avoid egress charges for bandwidth.